# Define Multiple Styles React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to define multiples classes in React just like in CSS?

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  header1,
  header2,
  header3,
  header4: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
}));
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm not sure I understand what you are asking about here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid [@material-ui/styles](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/) library usage does not work that way. Each key in the object you define represents one class name.

So trying to do something like this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    'header1, header2, header3, header4': {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
}));
```

Will result in unusable or invalid class names when the code gets compiled to CSS, because the library will try to compile `'header1, header2, header3, header4'` into one class, and since the name contains a space character, the result is garbage.

To solve your problem, the closest thing I can come up with is to define the styles object as its own constant, then assign it to the needed keys. You can also override the original object using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). Something like:

```
const headerStyles = {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center'
};
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    header1: headerStyles,
    header2: headerStyles,
    header3: headerStyles,
    header4: {
        ...headerStyles,
        color: 'red'
    }
}));
```

I hope this is a close-enough compromise for you.

Comment: what if i want to add another styles to header1 only? How would i do it?

Comment: I'll add something to address that, you'll need to extend the original object.

Comment: I guess this is the best way possible. Thanks for it

Answer (score 0):

You're currently defining an object in the `makeStyles` method. this ain't CSS.

If you prefer CSS syntax over JSS, you can use the [jss-plugin-template](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-template/) plugin.

And write something like this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: `
    .header1,
    .header2,
    .header3,
    .header4 {
      display: flex;
      justifyContent: center;
    }
  `
});
```

Reference: https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#string-templates

Comment: Good but i dont to add another package :(